# Localized.strings does not always update until app is completely deleted and reinstalled

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

When I put my app onto my phone after changing some images or the values in Localized.strings, it doesn't always update. I end up having to completely delete the app from the device then reupload the project to get the new changes in.

Would this be a problem for people who are updating their app from the app store? I just pushed out my first app and my update is waiting for review, so I was wondering if people would have to delete their old app or if there's a way to avoid this problem on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't be an issue. Resources like `Localized.strings` are reloaded from the app bundle when the app is updated from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you are putting the application in your phone using XCode (ad-hoc build) then you should clean the build and then run it, in case there is bundle file changes. Always press CMD+Shift+K to clean the build and then CMD+R to run it on device. You do not need to delete the app from device. XCode should build it with latest bundle content and you should see updated data.